# override .ToString()

Tags: c#, overriding

I would like to override the .ToString() function so that whenever I get a double
it outputs only 5 digits after the decimal point.

How do I reffer to the object the .ToString is working on, inside the override function?
In other words what shell I put instead of the XXX in the following code?

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if (XXX.GetType().Name == "Double")
        return (Math.Round(XXX, 5));
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Why not just use the built-in formatting?

```
var pi = 3.14159265m;
Console.WriteLine(pi.ToString("N5"));
-> "3.14159"
```

For reference I like the [.NET Format String Quick Reference](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/msnet-formatting-strings.pdf) by John Sheehan.

Comment: +1 This is what the OP *really* wants to use. Sure, you can use as extension method, but there's really no point here...

Answer (score 12):

You can't override a method for a different type - basically you can't stop `double.ToString` doing what it does. You can, however, write a method which takes a double and formats it appropriately.

Answer (score 7):

As Jon pointed out, you can't override `Double.ToString`. You can create an extension method for `double` type that helps you do this:

```
public static class DoubleExtensions {
   public static string ToStringWith5Digits(this double x) { ... }
}
```

and use it like:

```
double d = 10;
string x = d.ToStringWith5Digits();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a format argument to `Double.ToString()` specifying the number of digits:

```
double x = 5.12345667;
string s = x.ToString("F5"); // s="5.12345", x.ToString("#.#####") also works
```

You can't override the ToString() function for doubles (it is a member function of struct Double)

Answer (score 0):

What class does your ToString() function belong to? Typically you have private variable inside the class you use. (But could also be a combination of variables to build a ToString())

e.g.: (pseudo code this is)

```
class MyClass
{
  private double dd;
  private string prefix = "MyDouble:";
  ...
  ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (dd.GetType().Name == "Double")
        return ( prefix + Math.Round(dd, 5).ToString() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I used what looked like the simplest one - use the "F5" formating. Still, If I wanted to use a different way of formating my double.ToString, e.g. I would like to add a string at the end of the conversion ("2.345" -> "2.345 double"). Can I add another member to the double structer with different signiture, which is close to a totaly separate function but more similar to the original?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot override, but you could a extension method

```
public static string ToRoundString(this double doubleValue)
{
   return Math.Round(doubleValue, 5).ToString();
}
```

usage

```
public void TestMethod()
{
   double greatValue = 3;
   string newString = greatVale.ToRoundString();
}
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

While the "F5" or "#.#####" solves the specifics of the original post, as the title is rather broader ("override .ToString()"), I thought I'd add that you can also create an extension method which overloads `ToString()`.

So, for example, an extension method of:

```
    public static string ToString(this double value, int roundTo, string roundSuffix)
    {
        string rounded = value.ToString($"#.{new String('#', roundTo)}");
        if (rounded != value.ToString())
        {
            rounded = $"{rounded}{roundSuffix}";
        }
        return rounded;
    }
```

Would produce "5.25 was rounded" if passed

```
double d = 5.2514;
string formatted = d.ToString(2, " was rounded");
```

or "5.2" if passed

```
double d = 5.2;
string formatted = d.ToString(2, " was rounded");
```

(just on the off chance there's some weird use case where someone wants to do something like that!)

You shouldn't attempt to override `ToString()` with a method that has the same signature as one of the built-in `ToString()` overloads however, as while the IDE will see it, it will never call the extension method (see [How to call extension method which has the same name as an existing method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524372/how-to-call-extension-method-which-has-the-same-name-as-an-existing-method) for details)