# How to call extension method which has the same name as an existing method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have code like

```
public class TestA
{
    public string ColA { get; set; }
    public string ColB { get; set; }
    public string ColC { get; set; }
    public void MethodA()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Original A1.");
    }
}

static class ExtenstionTest
{
  
    public static void MethodA(this TestA A1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Extended A1.");
    }
}
```

Now if I call MethodA like

```
TestA a = new TestA();
        a.MethodA();
```

It will always call Original method. How can I call the extension method.

Comment: Also a slight variation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303885/if-an-extension-method-has-the-same-signature-as-a-method-in-the-sealed-class-w?rq=1

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can't call the extension method as a normal extension method. The instance method overrides the extension method with the same signature

EDIT:

You can call it as a static method

```
ExtensionTest.MethodA(a);
```

Comment: that wont solve my problem. but thanks for answer..

Comment: You're welcome. The idea is that if you want to use the extension method as a genuine extension method, you can't use it if you have an instance method with the same signature because that instance method will always have priority over the extension method :)

Comment: +1 for being the first correct answer, Surprised to see it getting a downvote

Comment: I think I know who down voted it :P

Answer (score 19):

You can't call it *as an extension method*. It's basically useless at this point, in terms of being an extension method. (Personally I'd like this to be a warning, but never mind.)

The compiler tries all possible *instance* methods before it attempts to resolve extension methods. From section 7.6.5.2 of the C# 4 spec:

> In a method invocation of one of the forms [...] if the normal processing f the invocation finds no applicable methods, an attempt is made to process the construct as an extension method invociation.

and later:

> The preceding rules mean that instance methods take precedence over extension methods

You can call it like a regular static method though:

```
// Fixed typo in name
ExtensionTest.MethodA(a);
```

Answer (score 8):

[Extension Methods - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

> An extension method with the **same name and signature** as an
>   interface or class method **will never be called**. At compile time,
>   **extension methods always have lower priority** than instance methods defined in the type itself.

You can call the extension method as regular static method of a class.

```
ExtenstionTest.MethodA(a);
```

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

> In other words, if a type has a method named Process(int i), and you
>   have an extension method with the same signature, the compiler will
>   always bind to the instance method. When the compiler encounters a
>   method invocation, it first looks for a match in the type's instance
>   methods. If no match is found, it will search for any extension
>   methods that are defined for the type, and bind to the first extension
>   method that it finds. The following example demonstrates how the
>   compiler determines which extension method or instance method to bind
>   to.

Answer (score 3):

You can call extension method as any other static method:

```
ExtenstionTest.MethodA(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

as others suggested you can't call this method.the only way of calling it is such:

```
TestA a = new TestA();
ExtenstionTest.MethodA(a);
```

Comment: If others have already suggested it, what's the point of posting the same answer without bringing anything new ?

Comment: +1 for you.the new thing above was "only way" :)

Comment: Yes. But everyone else has already said that