# Default number format for ToString

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, number-formatting

Is it possible to define a default number format that is used whenever I convert an `integer` (or `double` etc.) to a `String` without specifying a format string?

C# example:

```c#
int i = 123456;

string s = "Hello " + i;
// or alternatively with string.Format without format definition
string s = string.Format("Hello {0}", i);
```

ASP.NET Razor example:

```html
<div>
    Hello @i
</div>
```

I think all these code lines implicitly use the default `ToString()` method for `Int32`. And not surprisingly, all these code lines result in `"Hello 123456"`, but I want `"Hello 123,456"`.

So can I specify that `"N0"` should be used by default (at least for `integer`)?

I already found the question [Set Default DateTime Format c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389187/set-default-datetime-format-c-sharp) - it looked good, but it doesn't help me for numbers.

---

***Edit:*** I'm aware that I could write an extension method which I can use throughout my application, but this is not what I'm looking for. I would like to find a property (maybe somewhere hidden in `CultureInfo` or `NumberFormatInfo`) which is currently set to `"G"` and is used by the default `Int32.ToString()` implementation.

Comment: can you do something with cultureInfo.NumberFormat, in the way your example url uses DateTimeFormat ?

Comment: This may be a bit too broad. Depending on the context, it's possible to do this. For MVC, you can create a DisplayTemplate and use `@Html.DisplayFor`. For some WinForms controls you can specify an attribute on a class property.

Comment: @TomBrown No, this is why I posted my question. :-)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109544/override-tostring

Comment: Why don't you customize  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat? E.g.  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That's not possible. *InvalidOperationException: Instance is read-only.*

Comment: I was going to suggest an utterly filthy hack involving using Microsoft Fakes to shim Int32, but it turns out that Fakes won't create a shim for Int32 - no idea why though unfortunately.

Comment: `int` types are implemented as `struct` in the background. They cannot be inherited from or overridden easily.  `CultureInfo` does not support this as the default `ToString()` method uses the `G` format, which does not allow for thousand seperator. So, No, this is not possible without extension methods. I would love to be proven wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your own `CultureInfo` and you can alter it and then assign it to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` like in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24785761/166921

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately, this doesn't help me because the `CultureInfo` is not the problem here. The correct culture is used, but the default `ToString` implementation uses the `G` format instead of the one I want (`N0`).

Comment: @fero I'm afraid that's not customizable. It's always `G`. And `CultureInfo` doesn't have much influence over `G` format (you can change separator but you can't change number of decimal places).

Answer (score 0):

You Can override systems toString() method into your class as under:

```
 public override string ToString()
    {
    int i = 123456;
        string s = "Hello " + i;
      return string.Format("Hello {0}", i);
    }
```

Comment: I don't have a class. I want to specify the default format for every `integer`.

Comment: In addition to @fero's comment, he could not subclass `int` even if he wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use extension methods

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToDefaultFormatString(this int i)
    {
        //Staf
    }
}
```

and your code look like

```
int i = 123456;

string s = "Hello " + i.ToDefaultFormatString();
```

Comment: But that's not what he's trying to achieve - he's quite clear that he's trying to control the result of ToString() on int.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to modify the functionality for a primitive type, which has no class, you cannot override the `ToString()` method.

You can however create an extension method.

```
namespace System
{

    public class IntExt
    {
        public string ToStringN0(this int i)
        {
            return i.ToString("N0");
        }
    }

}
```

and then use by

```
int i = 5000;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToStringN0());
```

The example puts the class in the `System` namespace so it will be available through the application.

Answer (score -1):

This maybe help you :

[Decimal.ToString Method (String) MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Double.ToString Method (String) MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[asp.net mvc set number format default decimal thousands separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086494/asp-net-mvc-set-number-format-default-decimal-thousands-separators)

Comment: No, this doesn't help me at all. I already know that the `"G"` format is used by default. But they don't say anything about specifying another default format.